# svn merge from trunk to branch conflict for a file deleted in the trunk

Tags: svn

After a subversion merge from trunk to branch, I got a conflict because a file has been deleted in the trunk and modified in the branch.
I would like to keep the trunk choice, but using "svn resolve --accept theirs-full" from the branch directory tells me

> svn: warning: Tree conflicts can only be resolved to 'working' state; '/path/to/file' not resolved

What should I do to have the file correctly deleted in the branch ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest if you reverted the other change, then merged in the trunk?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240425/subversion-merge-a-delete-command

Comment: I didn't find a clear answer in that question, so I posted mine. However I solved my issue following your advice, before merging I reverted the (branch) file to the situation it was before being deleted in trunk, and the merge has gone smoothly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what you want to achieve, you may resolve the conflict in any way svn accepts (seems that svn wants you to keep the file) and then remove the file by hand if it survives.